# not able to integrate perl script in shell script

Tags: xml, linux, bash, perl, shell

I have a shell script in which I also have perl script. I need to pass the variable value from shell script to perl.

Here is my perl script in which I am loading a file `client_23.xml` file and also `abc_lop.xml` file. I want these two values to come from shell script and then store the value of `$doc->toString(2);` in a variable or file so that my shell script can work on this file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

# Open the main XML file and locate the
# <block> element that we need to insert into
#
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => 'client_23.xml',
    no_blanks => 1,
);
my $block = $doc->find('/function/block')->get_node(1);

# Open the secondary XML file and find all the <ClientField> elements
# that contain the data we need to insert
#
my $abc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'abc_lop.xml');

for my $field ( $abc->find('/Hello/DataHolder/ClientField')->get_nodelist ) {

    my ($name, $pptype) = map $field->getAttribute($_), qw/ name pptype /;

    my $text = $pptype eq 'aligning' ?
        sprintf q{upsert("%s", "NA", $calty_strings)}, $name :
        sprintf q{upsert("%s", 0, $calty_doubles)}, $name;

    $block->appendTextChild('eval' , $text);
}

print $doc->toString(2);
```

Here is my shell script which is not integrated with above perl as of now:

```
for word in $client_types
do
    ## Concatenate the header, the contents of the target file and the
    ## footer into the variable $file.
    file=$(printf '%s\n%s\n%s' "$header" "$(sed 's/xsi:schemaLocation="[^"]*"//' "$file_location/${word}_lop.xml")" "$footer")

    ### I want my perl script to be here and output of that perl script should be an input to my below sed command

    ## Edit the target file and print
    sed 's|<eval>holder_clients = 1</eval>|<eval>holder_clients = 0</eval>|; \|<derta-config>|,\|</derta-config>|d' client_"$client_id".xml | perl -0pe "s#<function>\s*<name>DUMMY_FUNCTION.+?</function>#$file#sm" > "$word"_new_file.xml
done
```

So I want my perl script to be in the middle of my shell script as shown above. And instead of hardcoded `client_23.xml` name, I want to use `client_"$client_id".xml` and instead of hardcoded `abc_lop.xml` file, I want to use `${word}_lop.xml`. So I came up with below script which is using perl script as well but it doesn't work and it gives compilation error:

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly path_location="/export/home/rjamal/validation_test"
readonly client_id=43
readonly client_types="abc"

header='<hello_function>
<name>hello_function</name>'
footer='</hello_function>'

for word in $client_types
do
    ## Concatenate the header, the contents of the target file and the
    ## footer into the variable $file.
    file=$(printf '%s\n%s\n%s' "$header" "$(sed 's/xsi:schemaLocation="[^"]*"//' "$path_location/${word}_lop.xml")" "$footer")

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use XML::LibXML;

    # Open the main XML file and locate the
    # <block> element that we need to insert into
    #
    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
        location => '$path_location/client_"$client_id".xml',
        no_blanks => 1,
    );
    my $block = $doc->find('/function/block')->get_node(1);

    # Open the secondary XML file and find all the <ClientField> elements
    # that contain the data we need to insert
    #
    my $abc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => '$path_location/${word}_lop.xml');

    for my $field ( $abc->find('/HELLO/DataHolder/ClientField')->get_nodelist ) {

        my ($name, $pptype) = map $field->getAttribute($_), qw/ name pptype /;

        my $text = $pptype eq 'aligning' ?
            sprintf q{upsert("%s", "NA", $calty_strings)}, $name :
            sprintf q{upsert("%s", 0, $calty_doubles)}, $name;

        $block->appendTextChild('eval' , $text);
    }

    # writing into a file and thne this file will be input to my sed command below
    echo $doc->toString(2) > $path_location/client_"$client_id"_temp.xml

    ## Edit the target file and print
    sed 's|<eval>data_client_holder = 1</eval>|<eval>data_client_holder = 0</eval>|; \|<delrta-config>|,\|</delrta-config>|d' "$path_location/client_{$client_id}_temp.xml" | perl -0pe "s#<function>\s*<name>hello_function.+?</function>#$file#sm" > "$word"_dyn_model.xml
done
```

Comment: ... no, it wouldn't. `bash` and `perl` are different interpreters. What you're doing in your script can also be done with the perl script. And would be far less nasty than using `sed` to hack some `XML` you're parsing.

Comment: `-0` means NUL-terminated lines. `-0777` is what actually turns on slurp mode.

Comment: Note that it would be easy to write the whole thing in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `bash` script:

```
script.pl "$client_id" "$word" >"$path_location/client_{$client_id}_temp.xml"
```

(Or you can pipe the output directly to `sed` if you don't otherwise need to save the output to a file.)

In the `perl` script:

```
my ($client_id, $word) = @ARGV;
```